# Watching a value service value?

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have this in my Angular app:

```
myApp.value(mySetting, mySettingValue);
```

Is it possible to `$watch()` `mySetting` for changes? I've tried but can't get it to work.

This doesn't seem to do the trick:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return mySetting;
, function(newSettingValue) {
    console.log(Date.now() + ' ' + newSettingValue);
});
```

Comment: did you tried adding `true` for deepchecking watch. like `$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return mySetting;
, function(newSettingValue) {
    console.log(Date.now() + ' ' + newSettingValue);
}, true);`

Comment: watch is firing after changing the constant value..look at http://plnkr.co/edit/tW8QzmKn4zKTt1bhaE0y?p=preview

Comment: Looked at the plnkr and yes, the watch fires the first time--only once, and not when it changes subsequently. :)

Comment: forgot to add true, now check this on click button watch is getting called http://plnkr.co/edit/9FjWAsdGgjAlxXsS6Wsy?p=preview

Comment: submit this as answer

Comment: I added the answer, Please do check it.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to `true` property as a 3rd parameter inside your `$watch`, adding `true` will keep deep watch on object

**Code**

```
$rootScope.$watch(function() {
    return mySetting;
, function(newSettingValue) {
    console.log(Date.now() + ' ' + newSettingValue);
}, true);
```

[**Example Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9FjWAsdGgjAlxXsS6Wsy?p=preview)